# Getting all recent posts of friends and self for a given user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to know if there is a single API call in FB's graph API, which will allow me to get all the posts of oneself and their friends given the users ID and ACCESS_TOKEN.

Currently I am solving the issue by getting the ID's of friends for every user and the users access_token to get the friends feeds.

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/friends_user_id/posts?access_token=my_users_access_token
```

This process is too tedious as I have to make this call for every friend. Is there a simpler solution ?

Comment: No, you have to call the `/feed` for each user, and there's no simpler way to do, you can try https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests or simple PHP `foreach();`

Comment: You could try using FQL instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the answer. The API is

https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/home?access_token=user_access_token